# Wix website that generates https request to query data periodically

Tags: velo

I am using Wix for hosting my website. I need a solution to enable Wix to generate https request periodically. The https request results would be used to populate Wix database. Can someone provide the pointer on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Job Scheduler](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-scheduling-recurring-jobs) to make [`fetch()`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-fetch/fetch) requests and use the [`wix-data`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data) API to store the results in a database collection.